# Javascript gurus convince me that I should use javascript over compile to js languages like Dart or Typescript

Tags: javascript, dart, client-side

Hello I am about to start developing massive frontend application and I researching what is my best option for client side ecosystem. I am a guy with Java background, doing Spring applications for some time and during my spare working on my private project that most of it's logic parts reside in browser. It's a web based image processing and diagramming application that requires lot of graphic processing, advanced user interactions like drag and drop and I expect codebase will be large enough. I had dealt with poorly written large js codebase. It's quite headache to me. Then I have developed bad reputation for javascript. Initially I was looking at Google web toolkit. But i found it's not suitable to my application, cost of developing in GWT was very expensive because of it's complex abstraction. I finished research and planning phase. Also recently I switching to Ruby for my day to day work.

I'm tracking [Dart language](http://www.dartlang.org) development since it's inception and very impressed with it. I love the features like classes, mixin, built in approach of library(For me it's the huge benefit over Javasript), Stream/Promise and Web Components. I like the it's nature of it's strictness. Optional static typing of dart language minimizes misbehavior of the application and help me write more effective/optimized code. Importantly I can apply familiar design patterns and programming techniques used in Java  world. Right now I'm decided with go with it or gave more points to it.

More recently I spent a lot of time in discovering more advanced usage of Javascript. Just finished reading John Resig's "Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja" and quite opened my eyes. I can see using RequireJS and Grunt can manage my large codebase. I read the arguments of people saying long time risks of using Dart. Concerns are:

1. Compiled javascript source code can have unexpected bug and possible to effect application behavior.
2. Javascript is evolving. Ecma.next promises nice features like modules, maps and classes. And even right we can write Ecma.next code using traceur.
3. If Google shipped native dart vm in chrome. Performance of my application will differ in other browsers. It's not good.
4. It's not widely adopted so when your application grow it's hard to find good people who code in Dart.

For me these are not convincing enough to give up on Dart. So if you have some interesting point on both Dart and Javascript side please tell me.

*This may sound like I'm confusing but it's just a part of my research. Of course there's other parts of development like app architecture/design and patterns in addition to particular programming language or technology.*

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576785/new-web-project-2013-should-i-consider-dart/17577226#17577226). As you can see in my summary, I also do not consider those points reason enough to discard the benefits of Dart. I would be mainly concerned about finding Dart programmers, given that you describe your application as massive, but Dart is very intuitive and can be picked up quickly by anyone with a background in a similar language.

Answer (score 16):

1) Dart helps a lot to abstract Browser differences away. I think such techniques are likely to have have bugs because of the moving targets. If you want to take care of browser differences by yourself this is also error prone (IMHO much more so) or you use libraries like jQuery which are also complex and likely to have bugs.

2) But I think this is one of the benefits of Dart that it helps bridge Browser differences. I think this is the biggest weakness of the suggestion to stay with JavaScript because it gets some cool features too. You can only use them when all target browsers support these features. In Dart you can just use most of these features.

3) What is bad if there is one browser with better performance?
You can still run the JavaScript version on Chrome even when it has native Dart support.

4) Good people are hard to find no matter what language. But I think good people are likely to jump on new technologies.
Dart is very easy to learn. The hard part are all the peculiarities you face when you develop for the Web (CSS, browser bugs, client/server app architecture, ...) The language itself is usually the least of the problems.

Answer (score 5):

I vote for plain vanilla JavaScript. Any time you introduce a new language that compiles to JavaScript you end up with another layer of abstraction beyond the numerous layers introduced by your framework. Your time is better spent evaluating JavaScript frameworks rather than learning a language that gets transmutated to another.

I've built large front end apps, and you are better off learning the front end technologies, because believe me. You'll need to understand them when bugs crop up either in your application code or the browser itself.

Since you come from a Java background, imagine every computer OS has at least 4 JRE's available and you aren't sure which it is. Oh, and all these JRE's are built by different vendors. Now you need to build a thick client GUI and you want to write Ruby that gets transformed to Java at compile time because you know Ruby, but not Java.

You are faced with the same situation.

Comment: "another layer of abstraction" that's not quite an issue if you write good and tested code in dart, compiler will generate more efficient js than handwritten one. I assume dart2js compiler is tested on all possible scenarios to minimize side effect. Think JQuery or Underscore as another layer of abstraction since I don't know every bit of it's internals. So I can see compiled code of dart:core as underscore and dart:html as jquery.

Comment: A layer of abstraction is necessary anyway like some JS Framework to abstract away the ugliness and limitations of JS and the browser differences. Why not using proper abstraction that offers tooling (autocompletion, linter, tree-shaking, minification, proper language, modularity, ...) all at once